# Is it possible to insert ddmmyyhh to text column based on now() value of timeuuid column

Tags: cassandra

I'm referring to one of the presentation slide from eBay - http://www.slideshare.net/jaykumarpatel/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices

[image]

I want to try out the same thing. Hence, I create the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE ebay_event (
    date text,
    eventtype text,
    time timeuuid,
    payload text,
    PRIMARY KEY((date, eventtype), time));
```

Then, in my PHP script, I will perform insert using the following insert statement.

```
insert into ebay_event(date, eventtype, time, payload) values('03031611', 'view', now(), 'additional data');
```

Instead of hard code value `'03031611'`, is there a way to tell cassandra, to generate `ddmmyyhh` based on the `now()` value of timeuuid column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are no such functions available in cassandra. You will have to create it in the language you are using.

> Values for the timestamp type are encoded as 64-bit signed integers
>   representing a number of milliseconds since the standard base time
>   known as the epoch: January 1 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT.

There are some functions available that can create date in YYYY-mm-dd format.
[Date from timeuuid](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html)